# Efficient Cocoa Animation w/raw bitmap data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation, nsopenglview, ciimage

I have a raw bitmap image of RGBA malloc-ed data; rows are obviously a multiple of 4 bytes.  This data actually originates from an AVI (24-bit BGR format), but I convert it to 32-bit ARGB.   There's about 8mb of 32-bit data (1920x1080) per frame.

For each frame:

- I convert that frame's data into a `NSData` object via `NSData:initWithBytes:length`.
- I then convert that into a `CIImage` object via `CIImage:imageWithBitmapData:bytesPerRow:size:format:colorSpace`.
- From that `CIImage`, I draw it into my final `NSOpenGLView` context using `NSOpenGLView:drawImage:inRect:fromRect`.  Due to the "mosaic" nature of the target images, there are approximately 15-20 calls made on this with various source/destination Rects.

Using a 30hz `NSTimer` that calls `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]` on the `NSOpenGLView`, I can attain about 20-25fps on a 2012 MacMini/2.6ghz/i7 -- it's not rock solid at 30hz.  This to be expected with an `NSTimer` instead of a `CVDisplayLink`.

But... ignoring the `NSTimer` issue for now, are there any suggestions/pointers on making this frame-by-frame rendering a little more efficient?

Thanks!

NB: I would like to stick with `CIImage` objects as I'll want to access transition effects at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every frame, the call to `NSData`'s `initWithBytes:length:` causes an 8MB memory allocation & an 8MB copy.

You can get rid of this per-frame allocation/copy by replacing the`NSData` object with a persistent `NSMutableData` object (set up once at the beginning), and using its [`mutableBytes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableData/mutableBytes) as the destination buffer for the frame's 24- to 32-bit conversion.

(Alternatively, if you prefer to manage the destination-buffer memory yourself, leave the object as `NSData` class, but initialize it with [`initWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/initWithBytesNoCopy%3alength%3afreeWhenDone%3a) & pass `NO` as the last parameter.)

Comment: An update: my original code generated a frame in about 19.3ms.  Using an NSMutableData object took 16.6ms.  Using NSData:initWithBytesNoCopy took 14.6ms.  So... about a 25% reduction in running time.  Great tip!  Thanks.